# Can't write date according to the content of the source

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, datetime, selenium-webdriver

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse some dynamic content from a webpage and write them to a csv file accordingly. The following script can do this errorlessly except for one thing ***`the date`***.

If you take a look at the content of that site, you can see that there is no year mentioned in that tabular data.

However, when I click on any cell under `Date` column header in the output file, excel by default count it as the current year whereas `the date` should be `2004`. How can I make the year `2004` according to what is being shown in the below image2?

Script I'm trying with:

```
import csv
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League/2004-2005/36.html"

def get_information(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    for items in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'table#Table3 tr')))[2:]:
        try:
            date = items.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[1].text.split("\n")[0]
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d').strftime('%d-%B')
        except Exception: date = ""
        try:
            match_name = items.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[2].find_element_by_tag_name("a").text
        except Exception: match_name = ""
        writer.writerow([date,match_name])
        print(date,match_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    with open("outputfile.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(['Date','Match name'])
        try:
            get_information(driver,url)
        finally:  
            driver.quit()
```

***This is how the date are being shown in the csv file:***
[image]

***This is what you can see in that webpage***:

[image]

Comment: You could either write directly in `.xlsx` format (using a different library), that way you can control the formatting. Or you could add the correct year to each cell.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Martin Evans. It would be great If I could add the correct year to each cell programmatically but unfortunately I can't find any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the correct year to the cell as follows:

```
import datetime

date = "05-15"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d').replace(year=2004).strftime('%d-%B-%Y')

print(date)
```

This would display:

```
15-May-2004
```

Comment: You are the life saver @Martin Evans. Thanks a zillion.